# Phrase for not making a big deal out of something that is a big deal?

Tags: phrase-request

What's the phrase for when you don't make a big deal about something that is a big deal?

I'm sure it goes something like "____ off" or "____ it off" but I can't think of what fills the blank and it's really annoying me!

Comment: shake it off, brush it off, no never mind

Comment: @WillowRex - What does “no never mind” mean in your comment?

Comment: @J.R. it is an expression that means, "no big deal".

Comment: @WillowRex - Perhaps so, but in a different sense than “shake it off” or “brush it off.” I’d use _shake/brush it off_ when telling someone to not get too worked up about something. (Example: “The coach yelled at me because I turned the ball over...” Reply: “Just brush it off!”) On the other hand, I picture “Never mind” used when someone wants to diffuse an argument or drop an issue. That’s also “not making a big deal about something," but in a different way. If I’m correctly interpreting this, I think it should be clarified for the learner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you might be looking for is

> downplay

which literally means to put less emphasis (down) when describing something (play).

If you must use something with *off*

> shake it off
>   brush it off

can be used if something has happened to you, and means to "ignore it", but not to deemphasize it.

[image]

> write it off

has the meaning to accept that something bad has happened.

> Write it off to experience.

Comment: Yes thank you! Shake it off was just what I was looking for